# Which Google authentication method i need to use for command line script in python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I really getting confused with Google OAuth 2.

My requirement is not to `redirect user` to `google login page` which they describe in all their docs.

My requirement is that i have the python  script which i want to run as cron job which can access my calendar events for read only purpose

All their docs say mentioning redircting to browser for authenticating the user but nothing is mentioned by which i can authenticate my personal account which is as simple like entering my `username and password` but i have found nothing in their docs

I read this

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#libraries

They told to use `JWT` but they have not mentioned how to do that in any code

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.
{
"iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
"aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"exp":1328554385,
"iat":1328550785
}.
[signature bytes]
```

I am not sure just accessing my personal calendar is going to be that hard in V3 of API

Comment: As far as I know you'll always need a browser, because google needs to ask the user's consent. I build a cmdline app with Google's exampel code that just dumps a URL on the command line that the user needs to copy-paste into their browser, they accept, get a token and paste that back into the terminal. It's less then ideal, however, you can't do without browser.

Comment: @Blubber but the user is me only. can't i add some `key /username/secret` in my script which can authenticate me

Comment: No, but you can run through the whole process once, retrieve a refresh token, and use that to get an access token each time you want to run the app. No need to open a browser and get consent each time, however, the refresh token might expire at some point, and you'll have to run through the whole thing again. This is actually what we use, in the process I mentioned above, we store the refresh token in the DB for later use.

Comment: @Blubber. Google says that refresh token expires after one hour. if i am running my script after 2 hours i ahve to manually get consent for that

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [`foauth.org`](https://foauth.org/) which makes OAuth 2.0 much simpler. You could also use the [`requests-foauth` library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-foauth) which allows to interact with `foauth.org` as well.

Another simple (I mean clean, concise, and pythonic) library to use is [`python-foauth2`](https://github.com/jackdied/python-foauth2), which comes with a full example using google APIs.

Some notes:

- OAuth2 Service account are meant for server to server applications, meaning it should not be tied to **your account** (or your calendar).
- For scripts, it's much better to follow the instructions for [OAuth2 for installed apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp); open up a browser to authorize the app / script and get a code that you can redeem for a token. The instructions for [OAuth2 for devices](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices) is almost the same but provides 2 codes, one to enter in a browser and one to store on the device (or both from a computer...).